# Unable to user link_to_add_fields method from railscast Nested Model Form #196/#197

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, web

First of all I watched [Railscast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Railscast #197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746006/has-many-through-nested-form-that-can-build-multiply-insctance)  and a lot of other similar questions.

Im getting the following error:

`Missing partial profils/compagny_fields, application/compagny_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/me/www/Myapp/app/views"`

It seems that its not a partial problem cause i can see the `puts` from my partial.

So on my models i have:

> CompagnyModel: belongs_to :profil`
>
> ProfilModel: has_many :compagnies, accepts_nested_attributes_for :compagnies

In my View I have:

> > <%= p.label :firstname, "firstname" %> 
> >           <%= p.text_field :firstname %>
> >
> > <%= p.label :lastname, "lastname" %> 
> >           <%= p.text_field :lastname %>
>
> ```
> <%= p.fields_for :compagnies do |n| %>
> ```
>
> > ```
> >    <%= render 'compagnies_fields', :c => n %>
> > <% end %>
> > ```
>
> ```
> <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Compagny", p, :compagnies %> 
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> <%= f.submit "save"
>   %>

Finally here is my partial:

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= c.label :name, "Compagny"%><br />
  <%= c.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", c %><br />
  <% puts "-----!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-DEBUG-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!-!------" %>   
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that single quote on

```
CompagnyModel: belongs_to :profil`
```

in the actual model file?

Is the partial form being called saved in "profils/_compagny_fields.html.erb" or in "compagnies/_compagny_fields.html.erb"?

```
<%= p.fields_for :compagnies do |n| %>
  <%= render 'compagny_fields', :c => n %>
<% end %>
```

Try building the Profil.Compagnies model in the console to check that it is valid

```
new_profil = Profil.new
new_profil.compagnies.build
```

In the Profil_Controller I take it there is a variable @profil = Profil.new?

```
@profil = Profil.new
@profil.compagnies.build
```

Does the views/profil/new.html.erb (or views/profil/_form.html.erb if you're doing the forms in that way) have the form

```
<%= form_for(@profil) do |p| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. You named your partial "compagny_fields" but you want to render 'compagnies_fields'. This was my problem, mayby it is yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing this

```
render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
```

to this

```
render(association.to_s , :f => builder)
```